# Android API1 signed key issue

Tags: android, dictionary, migration

I have used Android Map API1 but now we don't have the option to generate API Key for signed key.

Meanwhile API2 is using fragment and I have to recode completely. Is there any quick solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). If you look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey), you can see that v1 is deprecated and they are not supporting it any more.